# How to customize formtastic attribute :as=>:check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, form-for, customization

my problem is that I try to customize the formatastic view. But before I go into detail, I'll explain my model.

I have 2 objects with a n:m relation Shop and Category

Shop model looks like that:

```
has_many :shop_categories, :class_name => "ShopCategory", :foreign_key => "shop_id"
has_many :categories, :through => :shop_categories, :source => :categories
```

Category model looks like that:

```
has_many :shop_categories, :class_name => "ShopCategory", :foreign_key => "category_id"
has_many :shops, :through => :shop_categories, :source => :shops
```

And of course my m to n table looks like

```
belongs_to :shops, :class_name => "Shop", :foreign_key => "shop_id"
belongs_to :categories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "category_id"

validates :shop_id, :presence => true
validates :category_id, :presence => true
```

This works fine and the following command in my Shop view will list all elements from categories within checkboxes:

```
<%= f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :id => 'shop_categories' %>
```

**Here is my problem:** 
Within categories I have a name for the category and a picture. Now I want to display the picture next to the selectbox.

I also tryed to use `<% f.fields_for :categories do |category| %>` but rails wont go through all category elements.

Is there a way to handle all Category elements with automatic checked objects?

If you need more information, i will be glad to give all what you need to understand the problem. 
Thank you for any hint.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: Not yet, but I started a discussion on google Groups: http://groups.google.com/group/formtastic/browse_thread/thread/58956dd2a97f5c46. For Formtastic 2.0 it exist an "easy" solution, but i also want to figure it out for version 1.2.4 (actual release).

If I got an answer to the problem, I'll post it here, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding custom inputs:

```
# app/inputs/collection_check_boxes_input.rb
class CollectionCheckBoxesInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionCheckBoxesInput
  # [...]
end
```